# Selective join for two tables (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How can I join these two tables:

Table1

```
DOCNUM  DOCTYPE COST    POLINE*         
PO01        1       8       18334
PO01        1       17      18335
PO01        1       8       18336
PO02        1       16      18787
PO02        1       14      18788
PO03        2       14      18850
PO04        2       14      18894
```

Table2

```
DOCNUM  INVNUM  INVSEQ*
PO01    INV001  2365301
PO01    INV002  2365302
PO01    INV003  2365303
PO02    INV007  2365450
PO02    INV008  2365451
```

To give this:

```
DOCNUM  DOCTYPE COST    INVNUM
PO01    1       8       INV001
PO01    1       17      INV002
PO01    1       8       INV003
PO02    1       16      INV007
PO02    1       14      INV008
PO03    2       14      NULL
PO04    2       14      NULL
```

I have tried all kinds of joins, but the closest I got was using ROW_NUMBER() to join the two tables...

Most of the time I get this:

```
DOCNUM  DOCTYPE COST    INVNUM
PO01    1       8       INV003
PO01    1       17      INV004
PO01    1       8       INV005
PO01    1       8       INV003
PO01    1       17      INV004
PO01    1       8       INV005
PO01    1       8       INV003
PO01    1       17      INV004
PO01    1       8       INV005
PO02    1       16      INV007
PO02    1       14      INV008
PO02    1       16      INV007
PO02    1       14      INV008
PO03    2       14      NULL
PO04    2       14      NULL
```

(because the join repeats for each similar entry of the DOCNUM)

Or this:

```
DOCNUM  DOCTYPE COST    INVNUM      
PO01    1       8       INV003
PO01    1       17      INV004
PO01    1       8       INV005
PO02    1       16      INV007
PO02    1       14      INV008
```

(without any PO03 or PO04)

I was thinking of maybe numbering the DOCNUM, then I can join only if the count is '1', but I don't know how to count the unique fields:

```
Count   DOCNUM  DOCTYPE     COST            
1       PO01        1       8
2       PO01        1       17
3       PO01        1       8
1       PO02        1       16
2       PO02        1       14
1       PO03        2       14
1       PO04        2       14
```

So any ideas?

Comment: You mention you tried something but you don't post the SQL statement.

Comment: Don't you have a foreign-key constraint in your Table2?

Comment: Unless you have something else to define the ordering you are rather stuck. From what you posted even ROW_NUMBER is not going to work well because you don't have anything to use to order the data.

Comment: Awful table design IMHO.  Where are the PK?

Comment: There is no way to accomplish what you want because there is no way of determining the which INVNUM entry belongs with each DOCNUM entry. ROW_NUMBER is not going to connect the tables as it is independent on each table. You have to fix the database design first, then this part should be easy.

Comment: It's not clear for me at all what logic is required. And I see that `Table1` has duplicate rows - 1 and 3, this breaks the 1st Normal Form design which is really bad practice. You will always run into problems with design like that, I recommend changing it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiShakh, I was thinking of first summing the Cost in Table 1, and then joining it... but that will be a compromise (losing the detail).

Comment: I scratched in the database, and found "unique" identifiers... added them (marked *)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The schema is broken. You should have an additional column in those tables to match up the invoice number. Based on the info provided, the InvNum field could even just be part of table1, though I understand that this may only be a partial listing of relevant fields from those tables.

If you at least had a column in each table that made it possible to guarantee the order — even a datetime field — we could still do this. As it is, your records from table1 aren't even guaranteed to be unique — there is no primary key. That's not a good recipe for database success.

I can give you the query below, that will *probably* work, *most of the time*, but without storing more info the table, Sql Server is free to change the ordering of the rows on you at any time and break this, so that it can return inconsistent results over time.

```
SELECT t1.docnum, t1.doctype, t1.code, t2.invnum
FROM 
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by docnum ORDER BY docnum, poline) as ordinal
    from table1
) t1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    select *, row_number() over (parition by docnum ORDER BY docnum, invseq) as ordinal
) t2 ON t2.docnum = t1.docnum and t2.ordinal = t1.ordinal
```

Comment: Thanks @Joel. I tried something similar to yours, but I think y ordering of the row_number() was wrong in the end. Your solution works - Thanks! PS. I scratched around for a unique column, and added them to the question (marked *). Not sure if there is a cleaner solution available.

Comment: Okay, updated the answer based on the new columns. This should consistently product the same results... but I still think the schema is broken. Good database design will match up a column(s) in one table to the primary key in the other. Relying on order is poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE1 AS 
(
    select t.doctype,t.docnum,t.code, row_number() over (partition by docnum ORDER BY docnum, doctype) as ordinal
    from table1 t
),
    CTE2 AS
    (select tt.docnum, row_number() over (parition by docnum ORDER BY docnum, invnum) as ordinal from Table2 tt)

Select c.docnum, c.doctype, c.code, cc.invnum from CTE1 C
LEFT  JOIN CTE2 CC
ON C.docnum = CC.docnum AND C.ordinal = cc.ordinal
```